# Reorder arrays within json object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, sorting

```
var data = {
 chart : 'rank',
 labels: [
      {
       0: 'First Choice'
       1: 'Second Choice',   
       2: 'Third Choice',
       3: 'Fourth Choice',
       4: 'Fifth Choice'
      }
 ],
rows: [
     {
      0: 2,
      1: 8,
      2: 1,
      3: 30
      4: 4
     }
      ]

   }
```

Is there a way to reorder the results so that the rows are reordered highest to lowest and the corresponding labels are reordered too like the below:

```
var data = {
 chart : 'rank',
 labels: [
      {
       0: 'Fourth Choice'
       1: 'Second Choice',   
       2: 'Fifth Choice',
       3: 'First Choice',
       4: 'Third Choice'
      }
 ],
rows: [
     {
      0: 30,
      1: 8,
      2: 4,
      3: 2
      4: 1
     }
      ]

   }
```

So far I have managed to reorder the rows array using the following but stuck when it comes to labels?

```
rows = rows.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
```

Comment: sort of method can't use with Object

Comment: @PranavCBalan I have used sort of for an array after parseJSON(data);

Comment: you are applying sort method on the single element array.... I think you need to rearrange the value in the array element object

Comment: Thanks @PranavCBalan, I've got that. Looking for examples or more direction of how to achieve that

Comment: @PranavCBalan Sorry but that sentence doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: ___1)___ generate an array using the object ___2)___ sort the generated array ___3)___ update the object property value using the array

Answer (score 2):

Get the object values into an array and sort it. After sorting update the real object based on sorted array.

```js
var data = {
  chart: 'rank',
  labels: [{
    0: 'First Choice',
    1: 'Second Choice',
    2: 'Third Choice',
    3: 'Fourth Choice',
    4: 'Fifth Choice'
  }],
  rows: [{
    0: 2,
    1: 8,
    2: 1,
    3: 30,
    4: 4
  }]
};
// get object property name array
Object.keys(data.labels[0])
  // generate array with object values
  .map(function(k) {
    return [data.labels[0][k], data.rows[0][k]]
      // sort the array based on rows value in array
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
    // iterate and update real object
  }).forEach(function(v, i) {
    data.labels[0][i] = v[0];
    data.rows[0][i] = v[1];
  });

console.log(data);
```